# "Pittsburgh" Latrobe Airport public transportation

Tags: airport-transfer, buses, pittsburgh

I'm looking into how to access Latrobe/"Pittsburgh" Airport (LBE) from Pittsburgh without a car, I didn't find any info easily on the airport website or elsewhere.

What options are there to get between Pittsburgh and Palmer Airport without driving?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've already done some searching and found a few options, but since it's a commercial airport in a populated area I am thinking there may be more options like a better connection from nearby, a shared shuttle or something elsethat I'm not finding. I'm hoping someone will follow up with a better answer.

Getting to Pittsburgh from Latrobe I found these options:

- [Westmoreland Transit 2F](https://www.westmorelandtransit.com/pdfs/Route%202F-January%201,%202014.pdf) departs Latrobe Airport at 5:20a, 5:50a on Weekdays. $6.
- Amtrak train departs Downtown Latrobe (4 miles from the airport) at 7:22a daily.
- Greyhound bus departs Latrobe Airport at 4:30p, 7:25p daily. $15-20.

Getting to the airport from Pittsburg:

- Greyhound bus arrives Latrobe Airport 7:35a, 11:50a daily. $15-20.
- Westmoreland Transit 2F arrives at the airport at 5:25p, 6:15p, 6:55p Weekdays. $6.
- Amtrak train arrives Downtown Latrobe at 8:22p daily.

Comment: I suspect that this answer may be all the options that there are.  LBE only sees five flights a day (all on Spirit Airlines), so demand is probably low;  and the area does not exactly look heavily populated on [Google Maps.](https://goo.gl/maps/Knc1vz8X3Nm)

Answer (score 1):

I know another way, you can use a private transportation service like [Shuttle Wizard](https://shuttlewizard.com/) they can pick you up from wherever you are and take you to an airport, and they operate within all of the US. I've used it various times and it's been pretty helpful to me.